# Find palindrome with minimum difference

Tags: java, algorithm

Given an `array` of strings, each string has same length `m`.

The error between two strings `s1` and `s2` is defined as the sum of the absolute distance between the characters `s1[i] and s2[i]` in the English alphabet.

Find a lexicographically smallest palindromic string say `alpha of length m`, such that the sum of the errors between this `alpha string` and the array of strings is minimum.

**Example:**

```
array = ["aa","yy","mm"]
```

**Answer:**

```
mm
```

This is my code:

```
static String solve(List<String> list) {
    int n = list.size();
    int m = list.get(0).length();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append('a');
    for(int i=1; i<m-1; i++) sb.append('b');
    sb.append('a');

    int diff = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    String resp = sb.toString();
    char[] ar = resp.toCharArray();
    for(char k='a'; k<='z'; k++) {
        ar[0] = k;
        ar[ar.length-1]=k;
        int d = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            String msg = list.get(i);
            for(int j=0; j<m; j++) {
                int e1 = msg.charAt(j) - 'a';
                int e2 = ar[j] - 'a';
                d += Math.abs(e1 - e2);
            }
        }
        if(diff > d) {
            diff = d;
            resp = new String(ar);
        }
    }
    return resp;
}
```

**Constraints:**

```
1 <= n * m <= 2 * 10^5
only lower case english letters are used
```

My code is working correctly only when input string length is of size 2 or 3. But I am not able to find correct approach to solve this problem when input string length is more than 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My code is working correctly only when input string length is of size 2 or 3.

It doesn't actually work for some inputs with size 3. The reason is that your code never modifies the characters in the result other than at the first and last index. So the character at index 1 (for when the input has size 3) is never modified after its initialisation to 'b'. So for the example inputs with size 3 it is just luck that it works, but as soon as the expected output has another letter than 'b' at index 1, your solution does not work for size 3 either.

The key insight here, is that the optimal character at index `i` is the **median** of all characters found at that index, and at the mirrored index (so counting backwards from the end of the string).

Here is an implementation:

```java
    static String solve(List<String> list) {
        int n = list.size();
        int m = list.get(0).length();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        // Collect characters for the left half of the palindrome
        for (int i = 0, mid = (m + 1) / 2; i < mid; i++) {
            // Count the occurrences of all characters at this index and the mirrored index
            int[] counter = new int[26];
            int j = m - 1 - i;
            for (String word : list) {
                counter[word.charAt(i) - 'a']++;
                counter[word.charAt(j) - 'a']++;
            }
            // Get the median character based on these character frequencies
            int median = -1;
            for (int total = 0; total < n; total += counter[median]) {
                median++;
            }
            // Append this median to the palindrome
            sb.append((char)(median + (int)'a'));
        }
        // Complete the half of the palindrome with the other half
        return sb.toString() + sb.reverse().substring(m % 2);
    }
```

Comment: Hi trincot, can you please check my other post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77275688/find-common-item-in-sub-arrays