# Reduce time complexity to process sub-arrays

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity

For a given integer array of size n, find all possible sub arrays of size k which range from 1 to n.

Now find the common item which is also a minimum in all sub-arrays of size k, if no common item is found then use -1 and add that to the result list.

**For example:**

```
Input array : [4,3,3,4,2]
```

**Result :**

```
[-1,-1,3,3,2]
```

**Explanation:**

```
k = 1, [4],[3],[3],[4],[2], there is no common item so -1
k = 2, [4,3],[3,3],[3,4],[4,2], there is no common item so -1
k = 3, [4,3,3], [3,3,4], [3,4,2], common item is 3
k = 4, [4,3,3,4],[3,3,4,2], common items are 3 and 4, the minimum is 3
k = 5, [4,3,3,4,2], minimum common item is 2
```

**Constraints:**

```
size (n) of the array range is 2 to 10^5
Each array element range is 1 to n
```

This is my naive approach code along with comments:

```
public static List<Integer> solve(int[] ar) {
    // Get all subarrays in a map, with key as sub-arrays size from 1 to n and value as the corresponding sub-arrays 
    Map<Integer, List<List<Integer>>> map = subArrays(ar);
    int n = map.size();
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        List<List<Integer>> list = map.get(i+1);
        // Get the common minimum item and store in result.
        result.add(solve(list));
    }
    return result;
}
// Logic to check for a given subarray of size k, get the minimum common item
public static int solve(List<List<Integer>> list) {
    int n = list.get(0).size();
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    boolean found = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int num = list.get(0).get(i);
        boolean isCommon = true;
        
        for(int j=1; j<list.size(); j++) {
            List<Integer> arr = list.get(j);
            if (!contains(arr, num)) {
                isCommon = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (isCommon) {
            min = Math.min(min, num);
            found = true;
        }
    }

    return found ? min : -1; // Return -1 if there is no common element.
}

// Logic to check if the number is present in given arr
public static boolean contains(List<Integer> arr, int num) {
    for (int value : arr) {
        if (value == num) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
// Logic to find all possible sub arrays of size 1 to n and stored in map
public static Map<Integer, List<List<Integer>>> subArrays(int[] arr) {
    int n = arr.length;
    Map<Integer, List<List<Integer>>> map = new HashMap<>();
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        map.put(i+1, new ArrayList<>());
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < n; j++) {
            int size = j - i+1;
            List<Integer> e = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int k = i; k <= j; k++) {
                e.add(arr[k]);
            }
            map.get(size).add(e);
        }
    }
    return map;
}
```

}

Here I am using a nested loop so time complexity is O(n^3), also using a map to store all possible sub-arrays that increase space complexity.

How to solve this in less time and less space.

**Update:**

I further tried to reduce time complexity using [below code](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/minimum-common-element-in-all-subarrays-of-size-k/):

```
public static List<Integer> solve(int[] ar) {
    int n = map.size();
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        result.add(minCommonElementInSubarrays(ar, i+1));
    }
    return result;
}

static void minCommonElementInSubarrays(int arr[], int K) { 
    int N = arr.length;
    int c; 
   
    // If N is odd then update 
    // C as K >= (N + 1)/2 
    if ((N + 1) % 2 == 0) 
    { 
        c = (N + 1) / 2; 
    } 
   
    // If N is even then update 
    // C as K >= (N + 1)/2 + 1 
    else
    { 
        c = (N + 1) / 2 + 1; 
    } 
   
    // If K < C, return "=1" 
    if (K < c)
    { 
        return -1;
    } 
   
    // Otherwise 
    else
    { 
         
        // Initialize result variable 
        int ar = Integer.MAX_VALUE; 
   
        // Find minimum element 
        for(int i = N - K; i < K; i++)
        { 
            ar = Math.min(arr[i], ar); 
        } 
   
        // return the minimum value 
        return ar;
    } 
}
```

But still this code runs in O(n^2) time complexity, I want to reduce it further.

Comment: This appears to be a problem from a programming puzzle / challenge site. Could you, please, provide a link to the problem page?

Comment: If this code works, but the O/P wants to improve performance, would [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour) be a better place for the question?

Comment: It's possible to do better than O(N^2) if you switch your thinking around. Suppose you fix the subarrays to be of size `k`. It follows that particular value `v` appears in all of the subarrays if the distance between copies of `v` is less than or equal to `k`. You would then iterate on `k` as required but only have to check each unique `v` exactly once, which should be much faster than the current approach.

Comment: If you do post the question on Code Review, please add to this question a comment with a  link to the question on Code Review.

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer, this is the link https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/287458/reduce-time-complexity-to-process-sub-arrays

Comment: _"this code runs in O(n^2) time complexity, I want to reduce it further."_ Are you sure if that's possible? Is there any constraint on the solution?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur, I have added the range of array size and array elements.

Comment: how is 2 the min common item for k=5? It should be 3 no?

Answer (score 2):

In linear time and space, map each element in the array to the max gap between instances of itself, and the start and end of the array. To do this, you only need to keep track of the max gap seen so far per index and the last index each elt was seen at.

E.g. for [4,3,3,4,2]

```
elt => max gap:
  2 => 4 (max gap is with the left end of the array)
  3 => 2 (max gap is with the right end of the array)
  4 => 2 (max gap is between the two 4s)
```

Then, for a given value of k, the smallest value with a gap <= k-1 is the answer.

```
k=1: There's no gap of 0, so -1
k=2: There's no gap of 1, so -1
k=3: 3 & 4 both have a max gap <= 2, so min(3,4) = 3
k=4: 3 & 4 both have a max gap <= 3, so min(3,4) = 3
k=5: 2,3,4 all have a max gap <= 4, so min(2,3,4) = 2.
```

This can be done in linear time & space too; just create the map gap_to_min_elt and check all possible gaps.

Comment: You can further improve the solution by calculating the max gap only for the elements present in the first subarray [1,k] since an element not present in this subarray will not be a valid solution anyway. That might be usefull for low values of k compared to a big value of n.